# Mis archivos no se suben al repositorio de Github

Tags: git, github

Tengo un problema, al momento de ejecutar los comandos para subir mis archivos a github todo marcha perfecto sin ningún error, pero a la hora de revisar en el repositorio no hay nada, alguien sabe que es lo que podría estar ocurriendo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya intentaste con `git branch -M master` y `git push origin master` ?

Comment: Antes de hacer un push deberias hacer un pull para verificar que la conexion entre el repositorio remoto y local no es distinta, haz siempre eso antes de hacer un push como en este caso te recomiendan.

Answer (score 0):

You lo veo todo bien. El `git log` te está mostrando la revisión que creaste. Si lo que quieres es que lo que tienes en el local quede en el reposito remoto, te falta empujar:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo, al empujar al repositorio, pero no reconocía mi password (aunque la cambié y también con un token) con este código:

```
    "Jorge@DESKTOP-LU46J0T MINGW64 ~/Desktop/CursoGit/Proyecto web 
    Empresa A (master) $ git push origin master
    remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 
    2021.
    remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting- 
   started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for 
    information on currentl y recommended modes of authentication.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 
     https://github.com/JLaita/CursoGit.git/'

    
    $ git push origin master
    remote: Permission to JLaita/CursoGit.git denied to JLaita.
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/JLaita/CursoGit.git/': 
    The requested
     URL returned error: 403"
```

Había generado el Token versión Beta que reemplacé por la versión Classic... y listo! Comenzó a reconocer el Token y la sincronización necesaria para no ingresarlo todo el tiempo.